# Why and when is “der eine” justified over “einer”?

Tags: pronoun, definite-article

Two questions please.

(a) Can *der eine* in the following be replaced with *einer*?

(b) If yes, how is the meaning or nuance changed?

> Karl stand eng ans Büfett gedrängt, denn kaum hatte er sich angestellt, war hinter ihm ein Tisch aufgestellt worden, und **der eine** der dort sich niederlassenden Gäste streifte schwer, wenn er sich nur ein wenig beim Reden zurückbog, mit seinem großen Hut Karls Rücken.

The sentence is from Kafka’s *Der Verschollene* (*Amerika)*.  For full text, please click [this link for the Gutenberg page](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/amerika-168/15).

The thought expressed seems to be *one of* — i.e. an *unrestricted* member of a class.  In English, *the one* would require something to restrict (distinguish from others) the member being picked out, as follows for example.

> One of the guests brushed against Karl’s back.
>
> The tallest one of the guests brushed against Karl’s back.

If German works the same way in general, but there was a special circumstance favoring *der eine* in the quoted sentence, it would be very helpful to know what that was.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes, *der eine* can be replaced with *einer* here, although, as you expected, the meaning would change. The usage of *einer* is much like *one* in English and also *der eine* can be thought of as *the one*. It shifts the meaning from being *any one of a certain group* to *a certain one from a certain group*.

In this context, the *der* is justified:

> The one behind him brushed against Karl's back.

(Well, it was the hat but you get the picture.)

One could assume (I haven't read the book) that the next sentence further included references to him, since he is now established as a definite entity.

---

Of course this cannot be generalised. There are other usages of *der eine* where it cannot be replaced with *einer* without seriously changing the meaning:

> Der eine hat schon wieder eine Grimasse in meine Richtung gezogen!

With *der eine* it means that it's been the same person who kept pulling faces. If you were to use *einer*, it just means that it's the so many-th face thats been pulled at you, but from different people (likely also at different places to different times). Key words here for this type of difference are *schon wieder*.

Comment: Thanks.  But if you are proposing that “mit seinem großen Hut” is operating like “behind him” in your first example, that is hard to accept.  Unlike your “behind him,” the “mit” phrase is part of the predicate and does not qualify (restrict) “der eine.”

Comment: Another way to put it would be to say that you are reading the original quote as if it read:  “der eine mit einem großen Hut streifte schwer Karls Rücken.”  In this sentence, “der eine” would have raised no question in my mind.

Comment: The “Der eine” in your second example appears to be a reference to a thing already mentioned or otherwise singled out implicitly and therefore fits neither of the paradigms (“one of the group” or “the tallest one”).

Comment: @Catomic Does it really? Remember that this is Kafka we're talking about. Kafka loved long and complicated sentences with hidden references. From my native speaker perspective, I have no problem accepting a clarification after the usage of the *der eine*.

Comment: @Catomic Also my second example is just to exemplify that *der eine* can *not **always*** be replaced with *einer* without changing the interpretation. But it still losely fits the *one of a group* paradigm.

Comment: Thank you again.  Couple more questions please.  (1) Would you not accept “der eine” when the sentence is not long and complex?  For example, if the original quote simply read, “der eine der Gäste streifte Karl,” would you reject it and say it should have been, “einer der Gäste streifte Karl”? (Assume that it is the first reference to the group of guests or the particular one brushing against Karl, as was the case for the original quote.)

Comment: (2) When you say that an “einer” in your second example would mean “many undefined people,” are you simply emphasizing “undefined” or do you really mean “many”?  In English, consider:  “The boys apparently knew what he had done.  One made a face.  Another spat.”  Here “one” would be undefined but not suggest many.  Thanks.

Comment: For question (1), the original story does not mention again the man with the hat.  I am linking the segment. Please roll down to the sixth paragraph. http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/amerika-168/15

Comment: More on (1), I am trying to understand your answer as saying that, while “the one” in English may require an express grammatical qualifier (such as in “the one behind him”), “der eine” in German can make do with an implicit qualifier (such as the reference to the hat in the original quote, which is buried in the predicate).  If this is correct, I am also trying to understand when this “implicit qualification” is allowed.  (E.g. in a long and complex sentence?)

Comment: @Catomic Re (2) I edited the paragraph a little. It's the *schon wieder* that's making a difference.

Comment: Re (1): Your questions got me thinking more. I would not reject 'der eine der Gäste streifte Karl', I would allow it. Maybe *der eine* can work entirely without further specification? I'll have to think more. First thing to note, is that German is a lot more permissive here, according to what we've seen so far.

Comment: It's very instructive to be told that German is more permissive than English. The point of your second example is now clear too. (I don't know why @Jan does not work at the head of comment.)